# Linear and algebraic independence of exponentials

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

**Original question** Let $P_1,\ldots, P_n$ be distinct polynomials of a complex variable. We suppose that they are without constant term ($P_i(0)=0$). Is it true that the functions $z\mapsto e^{P_i(z)}$ are linearly independant (over $\mathbb{C}$) ?

**Late edit:** The proof given in the selected answer proves the following

**Theorem** Let $(P_i)_{i\in I}$ a family of complex univarariate polynomials without constant term. Then if 
$i\mapsto P_i$ is injective, $(e^{P_i})_{i\in I}$ is a family of (entire) functions linearly independent over $\mathbb{C}[z]$.

One then has the

**Corollary** Under the same conditions (no constant term), if the family $(P_i)_{i\in I}$ is $\mathbb{Z}$-independant, then $(e^{P_i})_{i\in I}$ is algebraically independant with respect to $\mathbb{C}[z]$.

**Proof** Call $G$ the family of exponentials ($G=(e^{P_i})_{i\in I}$). For every multiindex $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}^{(I)}$, one has 
$$
G^\alpha=\prod_{i\in I} (e^{P_i})^{\alpha(i)}=
\prod_{i\in I} (e^{\alpha(i)\,P_i})=
e^{\sum_{i\in I}\alpha(i)\,P_i}
$$
but the fact that $(P_i)_{i\in I}$ is $\mathbb{Z}$-independant (linearly) implies (and is indeed equivalent to) $\alpha \mapsto \sum_{i\in I}\alpha(i)\,P_i$ is into. One has, from the theorem, that $(G^\alpha)_{\alpha \in \mathbb{N}^{(I)}}$ is $\mathbb{C}[z]$-linearly independant which amounts to say that $G$ is algebraically independant over $\mathbb{C}[z]$.

Comment: Indeed it is. This can be shown by realizing that the sum of terms in the polynomial becomes a product of exponential terms, each of which is independent/

Comment: Could you elaborate this technically ? In particular you do not use the fact that they are without constant term and the conclusion does not hold when you take polynomials with constant terms.

Comment: @RushabhMehta You should write an official answer.

Comment: This question has been satisfactorily answered in MO [there](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/293965/linear-independence-of-exponentials). I'll put details later

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E.:  Any progress on this one?

Comment: @MartinR I must confess, I left this question until the end of the month (I am organizing a meeting).

Comment: The restriction $P(0)=0$ is unnecessary. Indeed, a nonzero independent term could be absorbed in the coefficients of the linear combination.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: What about $e^{p(z)}$ and $e^{p(z)+i\pi}$? They are linearly dependent since  $1 \cdot e^{p(z)} + 1 \cdot e^{p(z)+i\pi} =e^{p(z)}-e^{p(z)}=0$. – It would suffice though that none of the differences $p_j - p_k$ are constant.

Comment: @MartinR: right, polynomials that just differ in the constant term correpond to linearly dependent exponentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this has been answered affirmative in [linear independence of exponentials](https://mathoverflow.net/q/293965) on Math Overflow for the more general case of exponentials of entire functions of several complex variables.

In the case of exponentials of polynomials of a single complex variable it
can be proven with more elementary methods. Here is something I came up with.
The idea is to consider slightly more general linear combinations with rational coefficients, in order to make a proof by induction work.

> *Claim:* Let $P_1, \ldots, P_n$ be distinct polynomials without constant term,
> and $R_1, \ldots, R_n$ be rational functions, such that
> $$
> R_1 e^{P_1} + \ldots + R_n e^{P_n} = 0 \, .
> $$
> Then $R_1 = \ldots = R_n = 0$.

In particular, $e^{P_1}, \ldots, e^{P_n}$ are linearly independent over $\Bbb C$.

*Proof by induction:*

The case $n=1$ is trivial, $R_1 e^{P_1} = 0$ clearly
implies $R_1 = 0$.

Now let $n \ge 2 $ be arbitrary and assume that the claim is true for all smaller values of $n$. Let $P_1, \ldots, P_n$ be distinct polynomials without constant term,  and $R_1, \ldots, R_n$ be rational functions, with
$$
R_1 e^{P_1} + \ldots + R_n e^{P_n} = 0 \, .
$$
If all $R_k$ are zero then we are done. Otherwise (without loss
of generality) $R_n \ne 0$, and it follows that
$$
 \frac{R_1}{R_n}e^{P_1 - P_n} + \ldots + \frac{R_{n-1}}{R_n}e^{P_{n-1} - P_n} + 1 = 0 \, .
$$
Differentiating this identity gives
$$
 \left( \left(\frac{R_1}{R_n}\right)' + \frac{R_1}{R_n}(P_1'-P_n')\right)e^{P_1 - P_n} + \ldots +
\left( \left(\frac{R_{n-1}}{R_n}\right)' + \frac{R_{n-1}}{R_n}(P_{n-1}'-P_n')\right)e^{P_{n-1} - P_n} = 0\, .
$$
Now we can apply the induction hypotheses, since the $P_k - P_n$ ($k=1,\ldots, n-1$) are distinct polynomials without constant term. It follows that
$$
 \left(\frac{R_k}{R_n}\right)' + \frac{R_k}{R_n}(P_k'-P_n') = 0
$$
for $k=1,\ldots, n-1$, and consequently that the functions
$\frac{R_k}{R_n}e^{P_k - P_n}$ are constant:
$$
\frac{R_k}{R_n}e^{P_k - P_n} = C_k \in \Bbb C \quad (k = 1, \ldots, n-1) \, .
$$

If $C_k \ne 0$ for some $k$ then $\frac{R_k}{R_n}$ is a
rational function without zeros and poles and therefore constant.
It follows that $e^{P_k - P_n}$ and consequently $P_k - P_n$ is constant,
which is a contradiction to the assumption that the polynomials are
distinct without constant term.

Therefore $C_k=0$ for $k=1,\ldots, n-1$, so that
$R_k = 0$ for $k=1,\ldots, n-1$, which also implies that $R_n = 0$.

*Remark:* Instead of $P_k(0)=0$ for all $k$ it suffices to assume
that no difference $P_k - P_j$ for $k \ne j$ is constant. The proof
remains the same.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. You're right, generalizing the coefficients makes the recurrence possible. Of course, your computations live within the space of germs with respect to Fréchet filter (complements of finite sets). I adopt your answer.

Comment: Moreover, I think that your proof proves that $\{1,e^{P_1},\cdots ,e^{P_n}\}$ are linearly independant over polynomials, which would imply that $\{e^{P_1},\cdots ,e^{P_n}\}$ are algebraically independant. I must think of this ...

Comment: I think, I have a stable statement: _if the polynomials $P_i$ are $\mathbb{Z}$-linearly independent, then their exponential s are algebraically independent_ I'll add this in the question. It rests on your proof.

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E.: $P_1(z) = z$ and $P_2(z) = z + i$ are $\Bbb Z$-linearly independent, but their exponentials are linearly dependent.

Comment: Of course ! when I say "_if the polynomials $P_i$_" it is understood "under the same condition".  I put it explicitely in my late edit.

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E.: Apparently I misunderstood your previous comment :)

Comment: No problem at all. I detailed the proof which is easy from yours.